# Rscript file path with space on windows batch file

Tags: r, windows, batch-file

I have Google Drive folder saved in my windows. I have created the bat file in that folder to run R through task scheduler but it's not reading the file as there is a space inbetween Google Drive.

```
@echo off 
start "" "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH      
Rscript C:\Users\lol\Google Drive\Alpha\FINAL.R
cmd.exe
```

Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:\Users\lol\Google': No such file or directory

it should be the simple issue to resolve but I can't seem to find the solution. please help

Comment: Why do you quote the path in the `start` command line but not in the following one? have you already tried it with quotation once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each word seperated by whitespace in cmd is seen as the next command or parameter of a command. In your path you have a whitespace which effectively tells the cmdline:

```
Rscript C:\Users\lol\Google
```

and it expects to find the result there, which obviously does not exist. To overcome this, we need to ensure that the command passes a complete string to the next command, we then encapsulate the path in double quotes. This tells cmdline to grab the entire string starting from and ending by double quote as a parameter and the whitespace is ignore and is seen as part of the parameter, now your string becomes complete: and will be passed correctly:

```
Rscript "C:\Users\lol\Google Drive\Alpha\FINAL.R"
```